# Objective-C error "No visible @interface for 'XYZPerson' declares the selector 'saySomething'

Tags: objective-c, selector, superclass

I am  really new to Objective-C and when I was practicing the book exercises, I really am stuck here. Please help me solve this and I have been thinking what could cause this error for more than three hours. Still I didn't get it!

Best regards,
Raj.

Thanks in advance !

**main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XYZPerson.h"
#import "XYZShout.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        //XYZPerson *some = [[XYZPerson alloc]init];

        XYZShout *some = [[XYZShout alloc]init];
        [some sayHello];



        // insert code here...
       // NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**XYZPerson.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *secondName;
@property NSDate *dob;

-(void) saySomething;
-(void) sayHello;

@end
```

**XYZPerson.m**

```
#import "XYZPerson.h"
@implementation XYZPerson

-(void) sayHello {
    [self saySomething:@"Hello all"];
}

-(void) saySomething:(NSString *)greet {
    NSLog(@"%@", greet);
}

@end
```

**XYZShout.h**

```
#import "XYZPerson.h"

@interface XYZShout : XYZPerson

// -(void) saySomething;

@end
```

**XYZShout.m**

```
#import "XYZShout.h"

@implementation XYZShout

-(void) saySomething:(NSString *)greet {
    NSString *upperGreet = [greet uppercaseString];
    [super saySomething:upperGreet];    // this is where I get the error mentioned above
}

@end
```

**Got it working ! Thanks to @MatthewD , @trojanfoe , @JFS for your big help :)**

Comment: Can you include the code for XYZShout.h as well?

Comment: What happens if you change `- (void) saySomething;` in XYZPerson.h to `- (void) saySomething:greet;`?

Comment: added XYZShout.h MatthewD

Comment: will try your suggestion now..

Comment: MatthewD... :) It worked.. Now I get in uppercase :)

Why does it run when I change it to saySomething:greet and not saySomething ? Since greet is defined only along with "saySomething" !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Moved from comments into an answer...)*

*MatthewD: What happens if you change  `- (void) saySomething;` in `XYZPerson.h` to `- (void) saySomething:greet;`?*

*Raj0689: Why does it run when I change it to `saySomething:greet` and not `saySomething` ? Since greet is defined only along with `saySomething` !!*

When you call a method, the compiler needs to locate the signature of that method so it can verify that the method is being called correctly. The signature includes the method name and the number and types of parameters. The usual way of providing method signatures is by importing the header file that defines those signatures.

So, in `XYZShout.m` where you call:

`[super saySomething:upperGreet];`

The compiler searches `XYZShout.h`, which is imported by `XYZShout.m`, and `XYZPerson.h`, which is imported by `XYZShout.h`. In `XYZShout.h`, the following method was being found:

`-(void) saySomething;`

This matches the called method in name, but not in parameters, so the compiler does not consider this a match. No other definitions of `saySomething` are found anywhere, so it gives an error instead.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are testing inheritance so I will assume that `XYZShout` is supposed to be derived from `XYZPerson`.  If so follow the suggestion from @JFS and make sure it does actually derive:

XYZShout.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XYZPerson.h"

@interface XYZShout : XYZPerson

- (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greet;

@end
```

And also correct the definition of `saySomething` in `XYZPerson` (you missed off the parameter):

XYZPerson.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *secondName;
@property NSDate *dob;

- (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greet;
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
- (void)sayHello;

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure to set the `XYZShout.h` interface to `@interface XYZShout : XYZPerson`?

Comment: @JFS don't ask a question as an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: +1 as this is basically correct.  Popeye and mipe34; don't be so critical.

Comment: @Popeye, thanks for the hint but It was not obvious when I posted my question. `user2029446` added the `XYZShout.h` portion after my question. Please don't vote negative for helping peoples.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Thank you very much! You detailed answer is for sure much better. Thanks for your fairness.

Comment: @JFS This is a frustrating site and I don't know how many times I've left in a "huff".  Only to calm down and come back to it...  I am weak.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Not at all. You are great! But we have to live with "Them". Good luck!

Comment: @JFS I didn't down vote. It is more of a warning cause I have been seriously pissed off when I have been down voted for no reason at all. So I avoid down votes where possible unless the answer is absolutely incorrect and they don't change it to be correct. I have found that it is a lot of higher rated users who do most of the down voting.

Comment: Since I am new here I cannot say that, but you all helped me. Thanks :)

Comment: @Popeye: Sorry Popeye for blaming you! Thanks for the hint anyway.

Comment: @mipe34: thanks for the hint but It was not obvious when I posted my question. `Raj0689` added the XYZShout.h portion after my question. Please don't vote negative for helping peoples.

Comment: @JFS: It was just recommendation, and sorry for that, but before your edit, the answer looked more like a comment / request for clarification. Anyway, I did not downvote.