# No visible @interface for declares the selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

Following is my `Model.h` file:

```
@interface Model : NSObject
    - (void)loadSiteForTTSWithText:(NSString *)text AndVerseNumber:(int)versesNumber AndChapterNumber:(int)chapterNumber AndBookNumber:(int)bookNumber;
.... //few other methods are here
@end
```

I have imported `Model.h` into my `ViewController` and made an object for `Model` namely `model`. And then i access the methods in `Model` using model. All other methods are working just fine, but when I try to access:

```
[model loadSiteForTTSWithText:stringToRead AndVerseNumber:verseNumber AndChapterNumber:chapterNumber AndBookNumber:bookNumber];
```

I am getting the error:

```
No visible @interface for 'Model' declares the selector 'loadSiteForTTSWithText:AndVerseNumber:AndChapterNumber:AndBookNumber:'
```

I am not getting any errors on the other methods declared inside `Model.h`. What can be the issue?

**EDIT**
I have checked for duplicate files but couldn't find any.

Comment: you havent implemented the `loadSiteForTTSWithText:AndVerseNumber:AndChapterNumber:AndBookNumber:` method in **Model.m** file?

Comment: I have implemented it. But even if it is not implemented, if it is declared, it should not be showing any error right?

Comment: hmm right... your file exists in `Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources`.. ?

Comment: Where you add Model.h ?? i mean your viewCon.h or viewCon.m >>?

Comment: @AhmedZ.: Yes, of course it is there... Otherwise how can the other methods work? I know the problem is really weird, but I am really hung up with it.

Comment: @iPatel: I have added it in `ViewController.h` and imported `ViewController.h` to `ViewController.m`

Comment: not sure , may be it is silly but just try to add  Model.h in ViewController.m

Comment: @HarikrishnanT : Hey check this question out.. Same problem as yours.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10727677/1042240 and they found the solution.

Comment: heres another one with same problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14956270/1042240

Comment: how and where do you create object of model...?

Comment: @AhmedZ.: Thats what I told. I have checked for duplicate files, but couldn't find any. Also, in my case other methods are working.

Comment: @iPatel: Tried it but no use.

Comment: @NitinGohel: created object for `Model` in `ViewController.h` like this:
`@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
Model *model;  
}`

Comment: @iPatel: you mean how can I create object of a class?

Comment: create it such like   Model *model; = [[Model] alloc] init];

Comment: @iPatel: That was already done in `ViewController.m` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Create object means allocating it memory and initialising it. How have you done that?

Comment: @Puneet: `model = [[Model] alloc] init];` in `ViewController.m`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the error was but exiting Xcode and reopening it solved the issue.

Comment: Product->Clean did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The method declaration might be wrong.just create a proper syntactical method declaration if you missed the syntax in middle it will give message like that.check your method decalration protocol.It seems mistake is there in that..